# ajax wont refresh form after submit but posts data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is the code I have made for a voting system. this is outside of my main website a test. I am new to ajax and jquery and can't understand why I don't get the form resubmission after Form is submitted.
it still posts the data and if I were to refresh the page it will show the new results. from what i have found it is something to do with the ajaz part but im new to ajax and jquery

```
    enter code here


  <!doctype html>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Live Poll System in PHP Mysql using Ajax</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Live Poll System in PHP Mysql using Ajax</h2><br />
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <form method="POST" id="poll_form">
      <h3>Which is Best PHP Framework in 2018?</h3>
      <br />
      <div class="radio">
       <label><h4><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="Laravel" /> Laravel</h4></label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
       <label><h4><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="CodeIgniter" /> CodeIgniter</h4></label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
       <label><h4><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="CakePHP" /> CakePHP</h4></label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
       <label><h4><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="Symfony" /> Symfony</h4></label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
       <label><h4><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="Phalcon" /> Phalcon</h4></label>
      </div>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="poll_button" id="poll_button" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </form>
     <br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <br />
     <br />
     <br />
     <h4>Live Poll Result</h4><br />
     <div id="poll_result">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>


   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_poll_data();

 function fetch_poll_data()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_poll_data.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#poll_result').html(data);
   }
  })  
 };

});    
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('#poll_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var poll_option = '';
  $('.poll_option').each(function(){
   if($(this).prop("checked"))
   {
    poll_option = $(this).val();
   }
  });
  if(poll_option != '')
  {
   $('#poll_button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
   var form_data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    url:"poll.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#poll_form')[0].reset();
     $('#poll_button').attr('disabled', false);
     fetch_poll_data();
     alert("Poll Submitted Successfully");
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Please Select Option");
  }
 });

});  
</script>
```

this is poll.php

```
<?php

include("database_connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["poll_option"]))
{

 $query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_poll 
 (php_framework) VALUES (:php_framework)";
 $data = array(
  ':php_framework'  => $_POST["poll_option"]
 );
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
}

?>
```

this is what i have to fetch the data.

```
<?php

//fetch_poll_data.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=commentsection","root","");

$php_framework = array("Laravel", "CodeIgniter", "CakePHP", "Phalcon", "Symfony");

$total_poll_row = get_total_rows($connect);

$output = '';
if($total_poll_row > 0)
{
 foreach($php_framework as $row)
 {
  $query = "
  SELECT * FROM tbl_poll WHERE php_framework = '".$row."'
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
  $statement->execute();
  $total_row = $statement->rowCount();

  $percentage_vote = round(($total_row/$total_poll_row)*100);
  $progress_bar_class = '';
  if($percentage_vote >= 40)
  {
   $progress_bar_class = 'progress-bar-success';
  }
  else if($percentage_vote >= 25 && $percentage_vote < 40)
  {
   $progress_bar_class = 'progress-bar-info';
  }
  else if($percentage_vote >= 10 && $percentage_vote < 25)
  {
   $progress_bar_class = 'progress-bar-warning';
  }
  else
  {
   $progress_bar_class = 'progress-bar-danger';
  }  
     $output .= '
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" align="right">
     <label>'.$row.'</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar '.$progress_bar_class.'" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'.$percentage_vote.'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:'.$percentage_vote.'%">
       '.$percentage_vote.' % programmer like <b>'.$row.'</b> PHP Framework
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  ';
 }
}

echo $output;


function get_total_rows($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_poll";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

?>
```

and lastly this is what i have for my database connection.

```
<?PHP

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=commentsection","root","");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want the the page to perform a re submission when submitting the form? If that is the case, you need to remove the:

`event.preventDefault();` 
from:
`$('#poll_form').on('submit', function(event){}`.

The `event.preventDefault();` cancels the default action of the submit button, which is why no re submission is occurring.

Comment: OMG thank you so much!!!!! i have spent days googling it and couldn't get it to work!!!!! you are the best!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer - TLDR - fetch_poll_data declared in your first document ready function and cannot be used in the second.

(index):115 Uncaught ReferenceError: fetch_poll_data is not defined

You are declaring your fetch_poll_data() function in your first `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` and then trying to reuse it in your second `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` .

With JQuery you only need **1** Document ready function.

**Fixed using your code:**

```
<script>
    function fetch_poll_data() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_poll_data.php",
            method: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#poll_result').html(data);
            }
        })
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        fetch_poll_data();

        $('#poll_form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var poll_option = '';
            $('.poll_option').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                    poll_option = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            if (poll_option != '') {
                $('#poll_button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "poll.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#poll_form')[0].reset();
                        $('#poll_button').attr('disabled', false);
                        fetch_poll_data();
                        alert("Poll Submitted Successfully");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Please Select Option");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Recommendation for best practices**

I highly recommend changing the way you are using JQuery and Ajax. I also started as a PHP Dev and sending HTML to the browser was much easier than data only via javascript. But as browsers have become much faster and data flow is needed more often, I would recommend returning data only as JSONs and letting the client render the HTML, it's also much smaller and faster on the network side of things.

**SQL - Are you storing data correctly?**

Currently I believe you are adding a new row for each framework into a table called tbl_poll. This could become insanely large. Imagine you had 1000 votes a day per Framework, thats 5000 x 24 x 30 = 3.6 million records a month

Rather store your poll as intergers then add 1 per count. You are using PDO which can then execute SQL along the lines of `UPDATE Polls SET Votes = Vote + 1 WHERE Framework = "Example Framework"`

**Updating Progress Bars on Successful data return:**

Once you are sending numbers only. You can then update your Bootstrap Progress Bars using the following Javascript / JQuery. It will update the values and animation of the bootstrap progress-bar:

```
            let dataFromPhp = [
            {
                name: "exampleFramework1",
                votes: '5'
            },
            {
                name: "exampleFramework2",
                votes: '45'
            },
            {
                name: "exampleFramework3",
                votes: '21'
            }
        ]

$.ajax({
        url: "fetch_poll_data.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (dataFromPhp) {
            $.each(dataFromPhp, function (eachObject) {
                $('#progress-bar-id-' + eachObject.name).css('width', eachObject.votes + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', eachObject.votes);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: @R3AP3R TV I couldn't clearly understand what you meant. I do see another answer mentioned the whole event.preventDefault() that you had running on your form. I assumed that was also what you wanted but decided to give this answer as it does resolve the issue in the code you had posted. If you want the page to refresh, you dont need JQuery / Ajax. You could make this page entirely in PHP. Posting data to a PHP server with JQuery is to avoid page reloading

Comment: i have used only php for a comment section on the same page i used this code for but was just trying ajax/jquery out for the voting system as the flicker when you submit was annoying. also for some reason i never get a success alert

Comment: @R3AP3RTV that "flicker" is the page reloading. If a user has a slow internet connection and the site isnt caching properly, that flicker could be a whole new page reload. 

JQuery is great but if you are wanting to learn a new way to make dynamic front end stuff like Single Page Applications. I would recommend using something like React, Vue, Angular. Believe me, as someone who spent 3 years on PHP / JQuery, I would have rather learnt something that is much more modular and progressive and easy to scale. It will save you lots of time and effort in the future

Comment: thanks for the advice! I will definitely look into what you have mentioned. The only reason I am focused on this is as it's part of my course. I really appreciate all of the help and advice. first time using StackOverflow and it has such an awesome community